# Does a discontinuity come only from a variable in the denominator?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Does a discontinuity emerge only from an individual function that has a variable in the denominator? (Ignore piece-wise functions.)

Comment: It could also arise as the square-root of a negative number in the numerator.

Comment: Example, $\ln(x^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the class of functions you're talking about. If it's the class of rational functions, i.e. functions of the form $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus A$, $x\mapsto\frac{P(x)}{Q(y)}$ where $P$ and $Q$ are real polynomials and $A:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid Q(x)=0\}$, then yes, "discontinuities" appear exactly at the roots of $Q$. I wrote discontinuities in quotation marks because strictly speaking $f$ is not discontinuous in the roots of $Q$ as it is not even defined there. A function cannot be continuous or discontinuous where it is not defined. But if $a$ is a root of $Q$ but not a root of $P$ there os no way to define a value for $f$ in $a$ such that it becomes continuous there. In this very sense one might say that $f$ is discontinuous in $a$.